# Layered Navigation in Magento 2 Luma template

Tags: magento2, layout, layered-navigation, luma-theme

by default the left Layered navigations are hidden in Luma template. How do I un-hide the it. similar to blank theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the layered navigation accordion to start expanded, then the official information on accordion options is available here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html

The file which generates these for the Luma is in \vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\view.phtml

On line 36 you'd change `"active": false` to `"active": [0,1]` if you want the first two categories to be expanded, `"active": [0,1,2]` if you want the first three expanded etc.

Note that you should never change core code, and so you'd ideally  need to override this file in your own extension theme. (However, I am aware that Luma doesn't seem to be great for extension themes.)